# How to find where .apk is taking assets(pictures) from?

Tags: android, jar, apk, assets, dex

I opened .apk file(game) with various pictures I need to find. However I can't locate them in drawable folder. My guess is they are downloaded on the run. I can't find in 2 classes.dex files nor any other files any link to the website those graphical assets could be used.

I tried opening the .apk with various tools and even managed to unpack .dex files into .jar files and look inside of them but I am pretty confused with the amount of places to search through that I want some giudelines on where to look, because it's honestly much more complex than searching with inspect element and that's what I really expected it to be.

Comment: Games usually contain so many images that they are not stored as single file. Instead multiple images are often packed together into one file using a proprietary file format.

Comment: Ok, so what type of files am I looking for?

Comment: That depends on the game, the used game framework and the game developer.  There is no general answer. Every file of a certain size could contain image data.